# Export multiple clips from timeline in Adobe Premiere Pro

Tags: premiere, export

I have a long timeline and want to export multiple clips from it. I know I can set an in point and an out point and export that part. But since I want to export a lot of clips, it quickly becomes tedious to do it one clip at a time. Also, having the in and out of each clips persisted in the project would be great, if I need to export again sometime (using other settings etc).

Ideally I'd like to set multiple in and out points and then just batch export all those clips using the same settings, but I'm not sure if that is possible. I'm of course also open to other solutions to speed up the process.

I've seen guides on how to export multiple clips, but they have all been based on exporting actual clips on the timeline. I need to export parts of the timeline, regardless of the clips in it. That is, the parts of the timeline I need to export may be a part of a clip, or contain multiple clips. I want to set the start and end of each exported part myself.

Maybe there's some way using markers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Make a new sequence. Call it 'Clip 1'.

Drag your original sequence into it.

It will import as a [nested sequence](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/how-to/premiere-pro-nesting-sequence-cc.html).

Set your in and out points on Clip 1.

Duplicate the Clip 1 sequence, and rename it as Clip 2.

Open the Clip 2 sequence, and change the in and out points.

Select the Clip 1 and Clip 2 sequences in your Project window, right click on them and choose 'Export Media'.

The export window will appear.

Make sure that the Range drop down is set to 'Source In/Out'
[image: grab2]

Choose you export video format.

Click on 'Send to Media Encoder'

Media Encoder should open and export your clips.

If you change the edit your main sequence, Clips 1 and 2 will still export from their In/Out points.

If you need more clips, make additional duplicates of Clip 1 or 2 and adjust their In/Out points as needed.

[image: grab3]

Comment: Thanks @tomh, that will actually do the work! :) I was hoping for some elegant solution using just the sequence I already have, but that seems impossible. I will end up with lots of sequences, but it will satisfy my needs such as being able to batch export and to re-export the same clips again if needed. I think I'm going to use spanned markers in my original sequence to mark and number the clips I want to export. That gives me a better overview, and I can use the markers in the "export sequences" to quickly and exactly set the in and out points. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Glad it helped. If you put all your sequences in a bin (adobe’s word for a folder) it will help to keep it all organised.